# JavaScript - Diretórios de imagem

Tags: javascript

Estou com a seguinte situação: o javascript não encontra o imagem no diretório imagens/exemplo.png

codigo html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Java Script é um barato</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <script src="java-script/index-java-script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Clique no interruptor para acender ou apagar a lâmpada</h3>
        <div id="interruptor" onclick ="trocaImg()" >
            <img id="imagemInterruptor" src="imagens/desligado.png">
            <p id="msgInterruptor">Interruptor Desligado</p>
        </div>

        <div id="lampada">
            <img id="imagemLampada" src="imagens/apagada.png">
            <p id="msgLampada">Lâmpada Apagada</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

código javaScript:

```
var num = 2;
var imglampada = document.getElementById("imagemLampada");
var imginterruptor = document.getElementById("imagemInterruptor");
function trocaImg(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (num == 1){
                    imginterruptor.src = "/imagens/ligado.png";
                    imglampada.src = "/imagens/acesa.png";
                    document.getElementById("msgInterruptor").innerHTML = "Interruptor ligado";
                    document.getElementById("msgLampada").innerHTML = "Lampada acesa";
            }else if (num == 2){
                    imginterruptor.src = "/desligado.png";
                    imglampada.src = "/imagens/apagada.png";
                    document.getElementById("msgInterruptor").innerHTML = "Interruptor desligado";
                    document.getElementById("msgLampada").innerHTML = "Lampada apagada";
            }
            //garante que num fique alternando entre 1 e 2
                num = (num % 2) + 1;
        }, 1);
}
```

[image: imagem da estrutura do diretório]

Comment: tente usar `../` ao invés de `/` no começo, o caminho é relativo, acredito que o caminho absoluto só vai funcionar caso tu suba um servidor

Comment: não dá para saber se apenas esse `imginterruptor.src = "/desligado.png";` é o seu problema ou se há mais alguma coisa.

Comment: tentei tbm não funcionou, ai coloquei o script no proprio index e funcionou sem que coloque  ../ ou ./ ou /  ai deixei somente com imagens/desligado.png

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Vc pode ir na barra de endereço (este computador/documentos/ etc etc) e copiar o diretório direto de lá.

Vc pode tb como o amigo falou usar o caminho relativo, mas deve-se atentar quanto a mudança de diretorio.

Vc pode ver mais informações em:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/7f8f5899-5e3d-4ca6-9ba7-60953360ae23/caminho-absoluto-e-caminho-relativo-qual-a-diferena-entre-os-dois?forum=mvcpt